# Using reusable styles for ease of use, but best for speed of site?

Tags: html, css, performance

have a quick question that I'm sure someone can answer. Lets say I have reusable styles declared in my css file.

As far as speed wise, would it be faster for page load time if i have a bunch of class = left and class = right 's added to the elements on the html page or faster if i specifically add float to the elements in css?

Example:

Would it be faster to do this.

```
.left {
   float: left;
    }

.right {
   float: right;
    }

<div class="box1 left">float me left</div>
<div class="box2 right">float me right</div>
```

Or this.

```
<div class="box1">float me left</div>
<div class="box2">float me right</div>

.box1 {float:left;}
.box2 {float:right;}
```

Performance wise, what is a better way to go and why. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule when writing code, order of importance goes: 
1. Correctness 
2. Readability 
... 
1000. Speed. 
Speed isn't really a big concern. Everything processes so fast it's silly to compare what is faster. But to answer the question, the CSS file lives in the head of the HTML document. It is processed before rendering and applied to HTML elements as they are discovered. So, it would take more time to separately add individual stylings than to group them under one class.

Answer (score 1):

If styles are included in html head element or in-line, there won't be any significant difference.

On the other hand, if styles are provided as separate css files, then extra http requests should be generated to get these files too, which is slower and could end with blocking css for rendering the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that performance will be faster when you write CSS in html page.
Because when html page is requested the time to load an external css file and read it is reduced .
As when u write CSS inside html page , is will be loaded faster.